# If we want to do PPC then is Google Adwords Certification required?

Tags: google-adsense, ppc

I want to do PPC for my website. Then is Google Adwords Certification required? I have doubt on it. Anyone can do PPC?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need certification, why would you?

Google takes your money either way..!

When you buy a laptop, do you need certification?

However, if you want to sell your services, you still don't need it, but you can charge your clients more if you have it ;)

Answer (score 2):

For Doing Pay Per Click activity there is no need to have a PPC certified course. But since you are burning money, you must be sure about how to select proper Keywords for Your Business, Type of PPC bidding You have to do and also About types of PPC ads - they may be search, display or both, dynamic marketing and so on. The Google interface is quite easy and you can get accustomed in some days. You can take help  of Google also

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that certification exists is to highlight your understanding of the Adwords Tool. To use it, you do not need the certification.

**What does the certification get you?**

Well, for starters, if you want a job in an Agency which does PPC Campaigns, then it adds some weight to your candidature. If you own your agency, then it is one of the requirements for being a Google Partner.

**What does being a Google Partner do for you?**

You get listed in a listing of official partners, you get a nice badge to showcase on your site and collaterals. You do get a dedicated person from the Google's team who will support you in all your campaigns. You will get access to resources and training on newer features as well. Once in a while you will also get leads.

tl;dr - if you are interested in PPC, then go for the certification

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a Google Adword certification for personal usage.